# Keep input field on the next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a date filter for entries from database. On the first page i have a list of all entries. On the second i have the same filter and almost filtered by date list. 
So i want to keep values of filter from the first page.

Here is my code :

```html
<form action="filter.php" method="post">
 <label>From</label><input name="from" required="true" type="date"/>
<label>To:</label> <input  name="to" required="true" type="date"/>
<input name="" type="submit"  value="Search" />
</form>
<table>
...
...
...
</table>
```

Comment: you can post the values to next form or you can pass the values in url for this

Comment: thx, but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you post all the code. All you have is the form and nothing else, which is not showing how you are receiving the form values and calling form 2. Show that you have made some effort to solve the problem.

Comment: sidenotes: `type="date"` that is HTML5 dependant and not all browsers support that type. Plus, in not seeing what your PHP/MySQL looks like, makes it questionable; meaning, potentially using MySQL reserved words such as `from` and `to`. You may need to show your code for that. It's kind of guesswork here.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variable after pressing submit..
Therfore you have to change `<input name="" type="submit"  value="Search" />` to `<input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Search" />`

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $from = $_POST['from'];
      $to = $_POST['to'];
   }

?>
```

You can also store the variable into sessions, to access it from everywhere.

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $from = $_POST['from'];
      $to = $_POST['to'];
      $_SESSION['from'] = $from;
      $_SESSION['to'] = $to;
   }
?>
```

The third option would be, to set the method of the form element to `method="GET"`. After that you can access the values through:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
      $from = $_GET['from'];
      $to = $_GET['to'];
   }
?>
```

With the get Parameter you can also do a magic thing like: http://www.example.com/index.php?from=20150906&to=20150907.
So you get the values of the variable via the URL..

For more information see: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

I hope I could help you...

Comment: be careful with brackets Markus. I had to edit your answer. You had quite a few missing and would have thrown/caused parse errors

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you are using `POST`, you can access the values

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']])) {
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to   = $_POST['to'];
}
```

As user Markus already said, you should change your `submit-button` name-attribute to a self-explanatory name, to keep it easy to maintain the code and check, if this button was pressed.

You then have to set it via the `value`-attribute in your form.

```
 <form action="filter.php" method="post">
     <label>From</label><input name="from" value="<?php echo $from; ?> required="true" type="date"/>
     <label>To:</label> <input name="to" value="<?php echo $from; ?>required="true" type="date"/>
     <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Search" />
 </form>
```

Keep in mind, that it is never safe to pass unsanitized data. So you should consider sanitizing the user input. (for instance a given format like YYYY-MM-DD)